# Home-brew hanging for at least one hour, stuck while installing

Tags: macos, homebrew, r

```
 Kuns-MacBook-Pro:~ kunzhou$ brew install rstudio-server
 ==> Installing rstudio-server from homebrew/science
 ==> Installing dependencies for homebrew/science/rstudio-server:homebrew/versions/boost150
 ==> Installing homebrew/science/rstudio-server dependency: homebrew/versions/boost150
 ==> Downloading https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/boost/boost/1.50.0/boost_1_50_0.tar.bz2
 Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/boost150-1.50.0.tar.bz2
 ==> ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/boost150/1.50.0 --libdir=/usr/local/Cellar/boost150/1.50.0/lib --without-icu --without-libraries=python,mpi
 ==> ./bjam --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/boost150/1.50.0 --libdir=/usr/local/Cellar/boost150/1.50.0/lib -d2 -j4 link=shared,static install threading=multi
```

The above are my code in Mac OS X Terminal. My system is EI captain. I tried to use home-brew to install RStudio but it has been hanging at the last line for at least an hour. I have tried multiple times and restarted my computer, no luck. Any help is appreciated.